# When passing string from one view to other give null

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

When I was passing the string to first view to second view it gives me null in my second view.

It's print right on the first view.

please give me solution.

Comment: can you provide some of your code so that we can help.. we cant give solution without knowing what are you actually doing.

Comment: Please give us code. How and when are you passing the string, how is it defined on the second view controller?

Comment: Post your code. Otherwise noone can help you.

Comment: @Kevin:check this [link](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/passing-data-between-view-controllers/)

Comment: best method is to make property of second string in second view controller then import .h file of second view controller in 1sst view controller. then just string1 = string2 .. (string1 is the string of 1st view controller and string2 is the string of other controller class)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use NSUserDefault for storing your string and use it in your second view

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:yourString forKey:@"your key"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"your key"];
```

or second option

define string in your secondview

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *strForName;
@synthesize strForName;
```

use it in your first view when you push your controller

```
secondView.strForName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:yourstring];
```

Comment: NSUserDefault is not a good option here. He can use global variable declaration.

Comment: Global variable declaration is not a good option either.

Answer (score 0):

Define a method with string argument in second view and call this method in first view.

`[secondView someMethod:yourString]` in first view.

Define this method in Second view as following

```
-(void)someMethod:(NSString *)yourString{

 // Implement your code what you want.
}
```